# Loop through object to create new object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an object that looks like this

```
object_1 = [(1,"car"),
            (1,"stuff"),
            (2,"things"),
            (2,"more stuff"),
            (3,"less thing"),
            (4,"diff_things")]
```

And I need a pythonic way to loop through it and make it into this

```
[(1,["car","stuff"]),
(2,["things","more stuff"]),
(3,"less thing"),
(4,"diff_things")]
```

Seems simple enough but I cant seem to get it to work correctly.

Comment: It'd be easier to solve if you used consistent data types in your preferred output.  A list in some situations, but a string in others, is making it more difficult than necessary.  Your second result is (essentially) a call to `sorted(myDict.items())` after creating a dictionary with the contents of your first object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, if you normalize the output types, you can solve it like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in object_1:
  dct[a].append(b)
print(sorted(dct.items()))
```

Comment: Oh man thanks for the help! Still trying to get the hang of python.